# How to implement dynamic search in multiple db tables

Tags: sql, search

I have a database with multiple tables and a web user interface. I want the user the be able to search for data in the database.
The results for the searches can come from multiple tables and joins between them.

for example: parameter a comes from table A, b from table B ect', so if he searches for a & b he will get results from A & B.

So I was thinking to write a code that will generate a SQL query dynamically according to the search the user performs.

But this approach is very complicated to implement because I will have to generate a different query for each search - if he searches for 'a' so the query will contain 'A' and if he searches for 'b' it will contain 'B', and if he searches for 'a' & 'b' it will contain 'A' & 'B'.

So my question is - is there a easier way to implement search or do I need to write a code with loads of "if's"?

Thanks all

Comment: what sort of data is stored in table A and B? And how would one know if parameter a IS Really parameter a? How can someone like me tell? If you can decide the logic to that, then making the dynamic SQL will be easy

Comment: Also edit your question with your db tag,sql is just a language.

Comment: for a student my query will look like this: select * from A. and if he is searching for a grade the query will be: select * from B. but if he will search for a student's grade the query will be: select * from A join B etc'. so should my code generate a different "from" and "where" clauses for different search combinations?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how your DB is designed but you could design a searchingmechanism where the user could chooze which Database/s he wants to search (userfriendly identifiers of course at the frontendside). In your database you could specify a Table with meta-informations for your tables, e.g. Name of Table, Clumns to be searched etc.

After User tells Interface which Categorys(tbls) he wants to search you could mix the Parameter with a given index (you could count the commas) and then do a while loop for the count of the index searching the all tbls in that string, insert the RS into a Temporary Table #1, #2, #3, ...Select them and rterun them.

You have to consider different Datatypes etc. Its not that easy tbf